# Let $p_1=1,p_2=3x^2,p_3=x+x^2-3x^3$.Find subspaces $T_1,T_2$ such that $L(p_1,p_2,p_3) \oplus T_i = \mathbb{R}_3[x], i=1,2$ and $T_1+T_2=T_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $p_1=1,p_2=3x^2,p_3=x+x^2-3x^3$.Find subspaces $T_1,T_2$ such that $L(p_1,p_2,p_3) \oplus T_i = \mathbb{R}_3[x], i=1,2$ and $T_1+T_2=T_1$. Where $ \mathbb{R}_3[x]$ is a polynomial vector space with degree not bigger than 3.

So I need to find two one-dimensional wich fulfill the given requests. I've found out that $L(x)$ could be one of these two subscpaces but what I don't know is how to find the 2nd subspace?

Comment: The sum of two 1-dimensional subspaces is more often than not 2-dimensional. IOW, is it stated somewhere that $T_1$ and $T_2$ should be *distinct* subspaces?

Comment: No, you just need to find such subspaces that they fulfill the two given requests.

Comment: So, can you use my hint?

Comment: I've tried to use this "trick" $T_1=L(x),T_2=L(2x)$ that fulfills every given request, but also $T_1=T_1+T_2=T_2$ so I can't use your hint

Comment: What was the problem there? That looked good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trick question:

- $\dim L(p_1,p_2,p_3)=3$ and $\dim \Bbb{R}_3[x]=4$, so the direct sum condition forces $\dim T_1=\dim T_2=1$.
- If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are distinct spaces, then, as 1-dimensional spaces their intersection is trivial. Consequently their sum is direct, and $\dim (T_1+T_2)=1+1=2$. This is incompatible with $T_1+T_2=T_1$, because that would imply $\dim (T_1+T_2)=1$.
- Therefore we are forced to accept that in all the solutions $T_1=T_2$.
- Therefore you just need to find one subspace $T_1$, and set $T_2=T_1$.